# how to access UIView without using tag method

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have my own custom view and adding them dynamically to the UIViewController.

Those views are something like:

```
class pinView: UIView {


    var userID : String?
    var lastTimeConnected : Date?


    init(userID: String, lastTimeConnected : Date)
    {
        self.userID = userID
self.lastTimeConnected = lastTimeConnected

    }
```

I then add my view to the UIViewController by calling

```
 imageView.addSubview(pinViewInstance) in a loop
```

I have events that will trigger my views to move on the screen. I call a database to get their new position and then I need to update them. How do I get to the view by using the userID on my custom view? I would use tags but they are just INT and I need something much bigger than that. Otherwise I need to map the tags to the userIDs which I really want to avoid.

To be clear... I know I can do this:
let pinViewInstance = self.view.viewWithTag(numberHere) as? pinView
But what I want is to access it by the ID, the first reason why I extended the UIView class in the first place.

I hope you know how to solve this has been stuck on it for a bit and cannot see a way around it. Your help much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Two options:

**One:** iterate with a for-loop through the UIImageView.subviews that those custom-views had been added to. set each view to a pinView reference and compare the userID in it.

```
func getPinView(userId: String) -> (pinView?) {
    for view in self.imageView.subviews as [UIView] {
        if let pin = view as? pinView {
            if pin.userID == userId {
                return pin
           }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Two:** when you add the pinView add them to a dictionary with the userId as key. And when you need the pinView. get it with the key:

```
// init
var pinViews: [String: pinView] = [:]

// after adding subview
pinViews[pinViewInstance.userID] = pinViewInstance

// get pinView
let pin: pinView = pinViews[userID] as! pinView
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Really good solution, elegant and definitely beats using tag. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through `imageView.subviews` and find the `pinView` by using this class type check:

```
if type(of: aSubview) == pinView.self
```

Then you can access the `userID` and check for the right `userID`.